# What word to choose for the speed game?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

How do we describe a game when people do everything very fast to win?

Is it known as a **speed game**, **speed play** or some other word?

This [source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/race) says “a contest of speed, as in running, riding, driving, or sailing”. Does it mean we can use “race” only for these types of contests or it’s also allowed for another contests. For example: there’s a game where students should make up a sentence as fast as they can to win, is this game a race?

Comment: A [race](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/race) is any "contest of speed." Do you mean something else?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/race says “a contest of speed, as in running, riding, driving, or sailing”. Does it mean we can use “race” only for these types of contests or it’s also allowed for another contests. For example: there’s a game where students should  make up a sentence as fast as they can to win, is this game a race?

Comment: I included your example in the post. You can [edit] your post to make improvements.

Comment: Thank you, it’s okay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A race is usually used to describe when there is some distance to be covered, usually in the fastest time.

Doing things fast without covering a specified distance is more like a *contest*, *competition* or a *challenge*.